# submit form to page and depending on input show different div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I Have a form which when submitted needs to go to the page and then show one of 4 hidden divs depending on the page.

Here is the form

```
<form>
<input id="place" name="place" type="text">
<input name="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the page

```
<div id="brighton">
<p>Brighton</p>
</div>

<div id="devon">
<p>Devon</p>
</div>

<div id="search">
<p>search</p>
</div>

<div id="variety">
<p>variety</p>
</div>
```

So if Brighton is typed into the place input i need the form to submit the page and show the Brighton div and if Devon is typed in to show the Devon div etc and if the 2/12/2012 is typed into the date picker input and Brighton into the place input it goes to the page and shows the variety div.

i also need it so if the 1/12/2012 is typed in to the date picker input the page redirects to the **page show.html**.

any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy if you know PHP at all. It looks like you need a good, easy start. Then you will be able to achieve this in seconds.

Refer to [W3SCHOOLS PHP Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

To achieve what you have mentioned, first make the following changes in your form:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<input id="place" name="place" type="text">
<input name="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Create a new file called **submit.php** and add the following code:

```
<?php
$place = $_POST['place'];
$date = $_POST['datepicker'];

if ($date == '1/12/2012') {
  header('Location: show.html');
  exit;
}
?>

<?php if ($place == 'Brighton''): ?>
<div id="brighton">
<p>Brighton</p>
</div>

<?php elseif ($place == 'Devon'): ?>
<div id="devon">
<p>Devon</p>
</div>

<?php elseif ($place == 'search'): ?>
<div id="search">
<p>search</p>
</div>

<?php elseif ($place == 'Variety'): ?>
<div id="variety">
<p>variety</p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now the above example is not the complete solution, but it gives you an idea as to how you can use `if-then-else` construct in PHP to compare values and do as desired.

Comment: thank you this has been very helpful it didn't occur to me to use php if statements but now seems so easy.

Answer (score 1):

Post your form to a php page and then check the posted form parameters to determine which div to show.

```
<?php 
   if ($_POST["place"] == "Brighton") {
?>
    <div id="brighton">
    <p>Brighton</p>
    </div>

<?php 
  } else if ($_POST["place"] == "Devon") {
?>
    <div id="devon">
    <p>Devon</p>
    </div>

<?php 
  }
?>
```

Do that for each div and parameter combination. Make sure you set the "method" attribute on your form to "post":

```
<form action="somepage.php" method="post">...</form>
```

In the resulting HTML you will only see the one that matches the form parameter.